# Access AWS Api Gateway API from localhost without auth gives Missing Authentication Token

Tags: amazon-web-services, express, aws-api-gateway

I set up my first API Gateway in AWS and trying to access the API from A Express route. This gives the following error: `{"message":"Missing Authentication Token"}`.

When accessing the exact same API through Postman it works fine!

Code is as followed:

```
router.get(
    '/users',
    async (req, res) => {
        console.log(`${API_BASE_URL}/users}`);
        try {
            const apiRes = await needle('post', `${API_BASE_URL}/users}`)
            const data = apiRes.body;

            res.status(200).json(data);
        } catch(e) {
            res.status(500).json({error})
        }
    }
);
```

The logged url works fine as a post request in Postman.

Comment: you sure this is like this: `${API_BASE_URL}/users}` and not like this:`${API_BASE_URL}/users`

Comment: @Woohaik Somehow completely missed that... thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Completely missed the extra `}` in `${API_BASE_URL}/users}`